# Why can I not open the desktop and core folders in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I think the problem is caused beacuse I have two JDK's. One dedicated one and another integrated from Android Studio. Before, when I start the bulid it gave me a warning:

`[options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6`

There is only one search I found online that did not help me.

But I can no longer reproduce this.
Can anyone help me? I dont know what I am doing wrong.
I cannot run the project, nor browse the folders in Android Studio.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Problem]

Comment: What's the issue exactly? You mention that you can't open desktop/core folders in libGDX, yet you display a screenshot of Android Studio.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I meant importing a libGDX project into Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The project doesn't appear to be imported into android studio.

```
Select File -> Close 
Import project (gradle)
```

Alternatively if you've already imported it you may just be opening it wrong.

```
File -> Close
Open existing Android Studio project (selecting the project at the root level)
```